# What do I need to host an Angular 5 application?

Tags: node.js, angular, hosting

My dad is customer of the hosting provider [combell](https://www.combell.com/nl/)

Where he has the default package now I am wondering if I can put the Angular 5 application I am making on there. I called their support and they say it's not possible but what do I need then? Is it so special to find a hosting provider that has node.js on their servers or is there a way around so I can host my Angular application on a non node.js server?

Comment: Basic hosting sites usually look for an index.html to begin their work. If you just copy paste the contents of your dist (the one that is generated with `ng build --prod` for angular-cli) files I think it will work.

Comment: I'm going to try that when I'm home, sounds like that would work. Maybe my relative path urls won't work but i'll give it a try! Thanks

Comment: And this does not seem to work I made another stackoverflow question for this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294514/angular-5-error-404-when-copying-dist-to-webserver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To host an Angular application, all you need to have is a server.

It can be NodeJs, Apache, Nginx, ...

The only requirement is that you must expose your `index.html` file. If your application is bundled (via, for instance, `ng buid --prod`), then you won't have to do anything.

This answer is valid for Angular applications, as you asked. Keep in mind that if you need to add a back-end (which is not an Angular application), you will need some other things.

Comment: Why can't the support staff of the biggest hosting provider here tell me something like that, they even connected me through to one of their web developers? :) thanks tho

Comment: I wont say they're morons, just think it loud enough for you to hear it :) Most companies targething the average Joe nowadays don't hire skilled people. If you have questions, post them here, we will be more useful than them !

Comment: Any idea what to do when that fails? :)

Comment: When what fails ?

Comment: I made another question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294514/angular-5-error-404-when-copying-dist-to-webserver)

Answer (score 1):

You just do `ng build` build and copy the content of the dist folder to any server. You may also do some additional configuration to [re-route it to index](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) and set the correct [href](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag). You can read more about it in the documentation.

Comment: I took a look and what you reffer to is that my relative path urls like ../../assets/images has to be assets/images so the base href has to change or am I seeing it wrong?

Comment: And this does not seem to work I made another stackoverflow question for this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294514/angular-5-error-404-when-copying-dist-to-webserver)