# Angular 5 error 404 when copying dist to webserver

Tags: angular, hosting, github-pages

I made a simple Angular 5 cover to say that I'm still constructing this website.
`ng serve` works fine locally, but now I wanted to host this on my schools website [here](http://users.hogent.be/~320255eg/) and I get all these 404 resources not found and all I did was copy whats in the dist/ folder after running `ng build --prod` to the www/ folder on the webserver.

It's angular 5 with this cli version:

```
 "@angular/cli": "~1.7.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
```

I tried to push another one to github-pages and this has the same problem [githubpages](https://ewoutg.github.io/underconstruction/) the repo is [repo](https://github.com/ewoutG/underconstruction) but it's almost an empty repo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `--base-href` parameter when you build your application, like this:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /~320255eg/
```

Where `/~320255eg/` represents the path to your application.

Comment: Sounds plausible, I'll definitely try this! and I just bought a domain what url do I have to use there it's like this: www.blabla.be, will no --base-href work here?

Comment: When you app is hosted directly under the root folder of your domain, you won't need to set it, notice that by default, its value is set to `/` (root)

Comment: Your base href will be what you put after the first slash of your domain name, for instance in your github pages it will be `/underconstruction`

Comment: is this the same as typing this in `index.htm`l file `<base-href="">` ?

Comment: Yes! :) It's the same

Comment: So building your app with the `--base-href some-path` will update this `<base-href="/">` tag.

Comment: Thanks you've both been really helpfull!

Comment: Not at all! :) So don't forget to accept the solution! :)